# how to get a part from a string with regular expression in C#

Tags: c#, regex

How do I get 'Name' value and 'Age' value?

**Case1 Data:**

```
aaa bbbb; Name=John Lewis; ccc ddd; Age=20;
```

**Case2 Data:**

```
AAA bbbb; Age=21;
```

My regular expression:

```
(?:Name=(?'name'[\w\b]+)\;)[\s\S]*Age=(?'age'\d+)\;?
```

But no way to get values(Name, Age).

Comment: If using RegEx is not important, you can use string functionality for this simple scenario. Split original string using ';'. After this you can split strings using '=' if it contains one. Simple !

Comment: Because I want to try to use RegEx.

Comment: Case3 Data:
AAA XXX=123 aa; bbbb; Age=21;

Comment: only output 'name value' or 'ages value'.

Comment: Note your sample data implied that only Name is optional.

Comment: @Wiktor Stribiżew Yes. 'Name' is optional.  Must have 'Age'.

Comment: Good, it means my original Case 1 part of the answer is what you need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Case 1: Only `Name` is optional

A regex for your case should account for an optional `Name` field.

```
(?:\bName=(?<Name>[^;]+).*?;\s+)?\bAge=(?<Age>\d+)
^^^                            ^^
```

See the [regex demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%28%3f%3a%5cbName%3d%28%3f%3cName%3e%5b%5e%3b%5d%2b%29.*%3f%3b%5cs%2b%29%3f%5cbAge%3d%28%3f%3cAge%3e%5cd%2b%29&i=aaa+bbbb%3b+Name%3dJohn+Lewis%3b+ccc+ddd%3b+Age%3d20%3b%0d%0aCase2+Data%3a%0d%0a%0d%0aAAA+bbbb%3b+Age%3d21%3b%0d%0aAAA+XXX%3d123+aa%3b+bbbb%3b+Age%3d21%3b)

If `Name` and `Age` data are on separate lines, use the regex with `RegexOptions.Singleline` flag.

**Details**:

- `(?:\bName=(?<Name>[^;]+).*?;\s+)?` - an optional string of subpatterns

  - `\bName=` - a whole word "Name" + `=`
  - `(?<Name>[^;]+)` - Group "Name" capturing 1+ chars other than `;`
  - `.*?` - any 0+ chars (other than newline if `(?s)` is not used)
  - `;` - a semi-colon
  - `\s+` - 1 or more whitespaces
- `\bAge=`  - whole word `Age` + `=`
- `(?<Age>\d+)`  - Capturing group "Age" matching 1+ digits.

[C# demo](http://ideone.com/dvZKto):

```
var strs = new[] { "aaa bbbb; Name=John Lewis; ccc ddd; Age=20;", "AAA bbbb; Age=21;" };
var pattern = @"(?:\bName=(?<Name>[^;]+).*?;\s+)?\bAge=(?<Age>\d+)";
foreach (var str in strs) 
{
    var result = Regex.Match(str, pattern);
    if (result.Success) 
        Console.WriteLine("Name: \"{0}\", Age: \"{1}\"", result.Groups["Name"].Value, result.Groups["Age"].Value);
}
// => Name: "John Lewis", Age: "20"
//    Name: "", Age: "21"
```

## Case 2: Both `Name` and `Age` are optional

Use optional groups for both fields:

```
(?:\bName=(?<Name>[^;]+).*?;\s+)?(?:\bAge=(?<Age>\d+))?
^^^                            ^^^^^                 ^^
```

See [this C# demo](http://ideone.com/1ip4Ct)

```
var strs = new[] { "aaa bbbb; Name=John Lewis; ccc ddd; Age=20;", "AAA bbbb; Age=21;", "Irrelevant", "My Name=Wiktor; no more data" };
var pattern = @"(?:\bName=(?<Name>[^;]+).*?;\s+)?(?:\bAge=(?<Age>\d+))?";
foreach (var str in strs) 
{
    var results = Regex.Matches(str, pattern)
        .Cast<Match>()
        .Where(m => m.Groups["Name"].Success || m.Groups["Age"].Success)
        .Select(p => new {key=p.Groups["Name"].Value, val=p.Groups["Age"].Value} )
        .ToList();
    foreach (var r in results)
        Console.WriteLine("Name: \"{0}\", Age: \"{1}\"", r.key, r.val);
}
```

Else, if you want to use a more regex engine-friendly pattern, use an alternation with 2 branches where either of the two patterns are obligatory 
(so as to avoid empty matches handling):

```
var strs = new[] { "aaa bbbb; Name=John Lewis; ccc ddd; Age=20;", "AAA bbbb; Age=21;", "Irrelevant", "My Name=Wiktor; no more data" };
var pattern = @"(?:\bName=(?<Name>[^;]+).*?;\s+)?\bAge=(?<Age>\d+)|\bName=(?<Name>[^;]+)(?:.*?;\s+\bAge=(?<Age>\d+))?";
foreach (var str in strs) 
{
    var result = Regex.Match(str, pattern);
    if (result.Success)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Name: \"{0}\", Age: \"{1}\"", result.Groups["Name"].Value, result.Groups["Age"].Value);
    }
}
```

See [this  C# demo](http://ideone.com/QVcs5V)

The `(?:\bName=(?<Name>[^;]+).*?;\s+)?\bAge=(?<Age>\d+)|\bName=(?<Name>[^;]+)(?:.*?;\s+\bAge=(?<Age>\d+))?` has 2 branches:

- `(?:\bName=(?<Name>[^;]+).*?;\s+)?\bAge=(?<Age>\d+)` - the `Name` part is optional, `Age` is compulsory
- `|` - or
- `\bName=(?<Name>[^;]+)(?:.*?;\s+\bAge=(?<Age>\d+))?` -  the `Age` part is optional, `Name` is compulsory

Comment: I am bit puzzled: both `Age` and `Name` are optional, right? If yes, you may either use `(?:\bName=(?<Name>[^;]+).*?;\s+)?\bAge=(?<Age>\d+)|\bName=(?<Name>[^;]+)(?:.*?;\s+\bAge=(?<Age>\d+))?` or just `(?:\bName=(?<Name>[^;]+).*?;\s+)?\b(?:Age=(?<Age>\d+))?` (with this one, you will have a lot of empty matches though).

Comment: <pre>(?:\bName=(?<Name>[^;]+).*?;\s+)?\bAge=(?<Age>\d+)|\bName=(?‌​<Name>[^;]+)(?:.*?;\‌​s+\bAge=(?<Age>\d+))‌​?</pre> not work.

Comment: I'm try (?:\bName=(?<Name>[^;]+).*?;\s+)?\bAge=(?<Age>\d+)|\bNa‌​me=(?‌​<Name>[^;]+)(‌​?:.*?;\‌​s+\bAge=(?<‌​Age>\d+))‌​? not work.

Comment: Yes, and [it works](http://ideone.com/QVcs5V). Do not copy/paste the expression from a comment, see it in the demo code. SO inserts garbage chars inside comments. I added this demo here.

Comment: '(?<Age>\d+)' should be changed to '(?:<Age>\d+)'

Comment: `(?<Age>\d+)` should be changed to `(?:<Age>\d+)`

Comment: If you want to match a literal string `<Age>` + 1 or more digits without capturing that information, you can. I doubt you really want that.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the regex you want.
`(?<Key>\w+?)=(?<Value>(?:\w|\s)+);`

This pattern captures key/value pairs into the named groups **Key** and **Value**.

This solution will fail to function correctly if a key name contains a space.

**C# Usage**

```
using System;
using System.Text;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
using System.Linq;

public class Test
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        string input = @"aaa bbbb; Name=John Lewis; ccc ddd; Age=20;";
        string pattern = @"(?<Key>\w+?)=(?<Value>(?:\w|\s)+);";

        var matches = Regex.Matches(input, pattern);
        foreach (var match in matches.OfType<Match>())
        {
            string key = match.Groups["Key"].Value;
            string value = match.Groups["Value"].Value;
            Console.WriteLine(key + ": " + value);
        }
    }
}
```

**Output**

```
Name: John Lewis
Age: 20
```

Comment: But the data may not Name or Age.

Comment: @Angelo can you update your question to include that detail? Its rather important.

Comment: Ok I'm sorry. Next time I will notice.

Answer (score 0):

...

```
.*?(?:Name=(?'name'[^;]*);)*.*?(?:Age=(?'age'\d*);)*
```

Comment: Please write an explanation of this pattern. Why does it work where the asker's does not.

Answer (score 0):

```
(?'name'\w+)[=]{1}(?'value'[\w ]+)
```

This Regex will give you `name` and `value` groups. In `name` you'll have *Name* or *Age* and in `value` *John Lewis* or *20*

You can see [how it works here](https://regex101.com/r/u7svgB/1).